# Add reference parameter to RoutedEventHandler

Tags: c#, static-methods, routed-events

How can I add a reference parameter to a RoutedEventHandler method?

---

I know that I can add a parameter with lambda like this:

```
check.Checked += (s, e) => Checkbox_Checked(s, e, additionalParameter);
```

However if I want to add a reference to the additional parameter, it says 'Cannot use `ref` or `out` parameter inside an anonymous method...'. This makes sense, hence my question, how can I define the function, that I can call it as follows:

```
check.Checked += Checkbox_Checked(check, new RoutedEventArgs(), ref additionalParameter);
```

The function then has to return `RoutedEventHandler`, which makes me come to this:

```
private static RoutedEventHandler Checkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ref List<String> additionalParameter) {

        return ??
}
```

What should I return, or is there a way better way to accomplish this?

@Edit 25-08-2015 - 11:48

To give some background information;

In the code I create checkboxes on the run, based on a selected item from a combobox. This can generate i.e. 20 checkboxes, which I want to have an eventhandler to add the name of the checkbox to the additionalParameter list.

This way I know later on which checkboxes are checked when I want to do some other actions.

(I am aware that I can also loop through all the checkboxes in the grid and gather the content of those that are checked.)

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`? In any case - having a return value on an event handler is probably a bad idea... What exactly are you trying to have it return, and why?

Comment: I do not want it to return anything. If I want a custom RoutedEventhandler with an extra parameter, it should not be void but RoutedEventHandler the compiler says.